# formulario: se debe elegir un producto y cantidad y de no ser asi no debe permitir enviar la informacion

Tags: html

Necesito saber cómo condicionar mi formulario para que no permita enviar los datos hasta que se haya elegido una de las opciones de una lista desplegable.

```html
<select>

  <option value="Excelente">grosella</option><br>
  <option value="Muy Bueno">pera</option><br>
  <option value="Bueno"> banano</option><br>
  <option value="Regular"> coco</option><br><br>
  <option value="Malo"> manzana</option>

  <label>Nombre: </label>

</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

El atributo `required` es un atributo booleano. Cuando está presente, especifica que el elemento debe completarse antes de enviar el formulario.

Al incluir el atributo `required`, se debe proporcionar una indicación visible cerca del control que informe al usuario de que `<input>`, `<select>` o `<textarea>` es necesario.

```
<select name="flavor" id="flavor" required>
```

[Developer Mozilla HTML attribute: require](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>El atributo SELECT requerido</h1>
  <p>El usuario debe seleccionar un valor antes de enviar el formulario:</p>

  <form action="#">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="flavor">Por favor elije un sabor:</label>
        <select name="flavor" id="flavor" required>
          <option value="">None</option>
          <option value="grosella">Grosella</option>
          <option value="pera">Pera</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
          <option value="coco">Coco</option>
          <option value="manzana">Manzana</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="quantity">Cantidad:</label>
        <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" required>
      </li>
      <br>
      <br>
      <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
      </li>
      <ul>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```